# Overlay graphic border on img tags

Tags: javascript, css, border, image

I want to be able to overlay a graphic border on all images on a site without having to manually apply it in photoshop. The border I'm using is a rough 'distressed' graphic which therefore isn't achievable by using css borders.

My initial idea is to use javascript to dynamically add a surrounding div (or divs) containing the border graphic to all img tags although I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: @Joseph Nothing yet - I cant think of a CSS solution and as I mentioned, whilst I think javascript is likely to be the best solution, I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an alternative using CSS3.

**Example snippet:**

```css
img {
    border-width: 20px;
    -moz-border-image:url("border.png") 20 repeat stretch;
    -webkit-border-image:url("border.png") 20 repeat stretch;
    border-image:url("border.png") 20 repeat stretch;
}
```

​**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/ENggp/)**

**References:**

- [The W3C Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images)
- [The W3C Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-border-20021107/)
- [On Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-border-image)
- [On CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/)

*Disclaimer: CSS3 is currently not fully supported across browsers, this solution assumes we aim to move forward in web development to target modern browsers.*

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following JavaScript:

```js
var D = document,
    images = D.getElements​ByTagName('img');

function imageWrap(el, wrapper) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    } else {
        var wrapper = wrapper || 'div',
            d = D.createElement(wrapper);
        el.parentNode.insertBefore(d, el.nextSibling);
        d.appendChild(el);
    }
}
for (var i = 0, len = images.length; i < len; i++) {
    imageWrap(images[i]);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p3Wf3/2/).

References:

- [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.appendChild).
- [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName).
- [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore).
- [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.parentNode).

Answer (score 0):

You can make your border as a background image and put the image inside it and add some margin

check my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/killerbytes/DUuk2/)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do it with JQuery, I tested this script and it worked for me. I just gave the image a background image and added padding.

You would call JQuery in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Then you could try this script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('img').css({
            'background' : 'url(images/002.jpg) repeat', 
            'padding' : '10px'
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

You could replace 'img' with your class, for example '.border', you could adjust the padding as well, and you would just replace the url of the background image with yours. Hope this helps/works!

Comment: [jQuery is not the answer to everything](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif).